# Can I stop linters from clearing the Problems tab before they have results?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-python

Is it possible to prevent linters in VSCode from clearing the current list of errors/warnings before they have the results ready?

I find myself using pylint a lot, but it can be very slow (3-5 seconds for a large file). Unfortunately, every time a file is saved or a problem is resolved, pylint will be re-run to analyse the code and while it executes the command, it clears the list of errors/warnings which is only repopulated after its finished.

I am using the VSCode-Python extension (v 2019.8.30787), however, this behaviour has been constant in each version I've used in the past.

Is there a way to stop this from happening? It would seriously save so much time if the list of problems remains there until pylint (or other linter) is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open issue on microsoft/vscode-python github: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/6579

And a suggested work-around for this is to not have linting on save. That way you can manually run the linters when you're ready to check again.